# Understanding crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, remote-debugging, crash-reports

My first app is now in beta-testing, and therefore I need to understand the crash reports that are being sent to me with our bug-system. For example the report under was sent to me just recently, and I have no clue what to make of it:

```
Crash due to signal: SIGSEGV(SEGV_ACCERR) at 22363030
0 libobjc.A.dyliblookUpImpOrForward + 48
1 libobjc.A.dylib_class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 28
2 libobjc.A.dylib_objc_msgSend_uncached + 24
3 Retrostock v2_mh_execute_header + 1388888
4 CoreFoundation__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
5 CoreFoundation_CFXNotificationPost + 1780
6 Foundation-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
7 UIKit-[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 312
8 UIKit-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1596
9 UIKit-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
10 Retrostock v2_mh_execute_header + 750904
11 UIKit_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 632
12 GraphicsServices_PurpleEventCallback + 528
13 GraphicsServicesPurpleEventCallback + 32
14 CoreFoundation__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+32
15 CoreFoundation__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 340
16 CoreFoundation__CFRunLoopRun + 1608
17 CoreFoundationCFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
18 CoreFoundationCFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
19 GraphicsServicesGSEventRunModal + 136
```

A quick google search tells me the app is touching memory somewhere it shouldn't. I've only tested on my iPhone 6 and this error was reported from an iPhone 5.

Generally I would like how to know how to relocate this error in my code, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash.  Do a google search to see how, but basically you need to have kept the `.dsym` file for that exact version of the app.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok, so I need to use the memory location of where it crashed, is this the 22363030 in my case?

Comment: @trojanfoe Also, all the answers seem to be having a crash report from the Apple, but all I got is the lines above, no file or anything, how is this solved?

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you understanding the crash report [Raywenderlich - Demistifying iOS Application Crash Logs](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs)

From the crash report most probably it's something related with rotation which cause it and `SIGSEGV` usually means invalid memory reference.

A better way to handle this kind of error is to use crash reporting tools such as `Crashlytics` which acquired by twitter and now part of [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) Using it they will tell you the exact problem what cause the crash and where in your code the crash happening. Have i told you that it's free??